# Memory usage of drawing image with CALayer

Tags: ios, memory-management, calayer

I want to know how iOS manages memory for drawing image. In my code I load an `UIImage` from net, and draw this image to the `CALayer` of my view using the code

```
contentLayer.contents = (id)(self.mpImage.CGImage);
```

I calculate the memory for this image as: `imageWidth*imageHeight*4 bytes`, that is about 7.5M in my case, but when I use `TOP` to see the `RSIZE`, I found the memory of my app increases 11M after I draw the image.I really want to know where the other 3.5MB is cost?

I didn't find any document explaining this, or found a similar question. Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you see any difference when for example using an `UIImageView` or `drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:`?

Comment: I need to custom my own view, so I didn't use UIImageView. With drawInRect, memory increase of my app is about mageWidth*imageHeight*4 bytes.